# nginx, how to append/hide parameter?

Tags: nginx

we have a working link ->
    `https://xxx.xxx.xxx/fuel/?action=fuel&apiKey=`

is it possible to hide `action=fuel` so the link looks like this?
    `https://xxx.xxx.xxx/fuel/?apiKey=`

```
conf ->
location /fuel {
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass              http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/internal.api;
}
```

Comment: Are these the only two params or there could be more?

Comment: at this point only two. maybe we can use $args but have no eperience with that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do it this way then

```
location ~ /fuel {
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  Host $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_pass        http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/internal.api?action=fuel&apiKey=$arg_apiKey;
}
```

Comment: Status Code:404 Not Found
apiKey example -> apiKey=84WN/iXAIFn2w8x8WgWYYb5/RRA=&vehicle=JR-481&date=20.10.2017

we already have /fuel and url so we just want to exclude action=fuel

Comment: You want to send `/fuel` as part of the url or not? Please provide sample input url and desired url on proxy_pass

Comment: yes /fuel is a part of the url.
Input -> http://xxx.xxx.xxx/internal.api/?action=fuel&apiKey=84WN/iXAIFn2w8x8WgWYYb5/RRA=&vehicle=JR-481&date=20.10.2017
Desired url -> https://xxx.xxx.xxx/fuel/?apiKey=84WN/iXAIFn2w8x8WgWYYb5/RRA=&vehicle=JR-481&date=20.10.2017